# Very simple JSON decoding

Tags: python, json, simplejson

I **have** searched for this, but all the results I find make no sense to me and seem too complicated. I'm looking to use either the `json` or `simplejson` module to get the value of a string in my object.

```
string = '{"name": "Alex"}'
```

Basically, I want to extract the value 'Alex' out of there. What would I do to achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is pretty straightforward using the [`json` module](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html):

```
>>> import json
>>> s = '{"name": "Alex"}'
>>> obj = json.loads(s)
>>> obj
{'name': 'Alex'}
>>> obj["name"]
'Alex'
```

If your Python is old enough that it doesn't have `json`, then use `simplejson` instead:

```
import simplejson as json
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not try reading the docs first? It's spelled out pretty clearly at http://docs.python.org/library/json.html

Comment: Where? I don't see anything about decoding a simple JSON object there.

Comment: @user1447941 Try looking again. http://docs.python.org/library/json.html#json.loads